# Loading a resource from within a class library in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a class library that has a method that is called from a parent project. I want the class library to load an embedded resource when a method is called.

Example: The console app has a class library called TestClass. This has an embedded resource called test.txt. When I call a method on TestClass, I want to read the resource test.txt.

```
Console App
  |  TestClass.dll
       |  test.txt
```

I have tried this code:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("TestClass.test.txt");
```

But this looks in the console app, not the class library.

I looked at this example: http://keithelder.net/2007/12/14/how-to-load-an-embedded-resource-from-a-dll[enter link description here](http://keithelder.net/2007/12/14/how-to-load-an-embedded-resource-from-a-dll), but this is loading the file from the parent app, not from within the class library itself.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `GetEntryAssembly()`, the code below gets the Class Library as the assembly.

```
public string GetResource()
{

    var assembly = typeof(TestClass.Class1).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

    // This shows the available items.
    string[] resources = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

    var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("TestClass.test.txt");

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

}
```